# Are there any sources on how many of patients with mental illness were hospitalized several times?

Tags: psychiatry, data

I was wondering how likely it is for someone with an mental illness like depression that after he is released is hospitalized again. Could you expect that someone who is released is never in the need of this service again? I wasn't successful with my web search, so I was hoping someone here knows some sources on this topic.
Im particularly interested in data from countries with good and stable public healthcare, preferably European.

Comment: There's a bunch of data-sets published june 2020 at [gov.uk](https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/ccg-outcomes-indicator-set/june-2020#data-sets), and a link to [previous sets](https://digital.nhs.uk/data-and-information/publications/statistical/ccg-outcomes-indicator-set).

Comment: @BitterDreggs You can probably just post that as an answer. Wouldn't need too much elaboration to fully answer the question.

Comment: @StevenJeuris Oh, alright then, I'll get onto it this evening. Thanks for pointing it out.